# Expect script issue with if statement

Tags: expect

I trying different approach to update existing expect script that I have inherit...
What I trying to achieve is to check Patch Level and depending on that, execute a set of commands.
But I can't make it work. :(

I tried as to below example and also tried with 'if' statement but I am clearly to fresh to solve this task.
I would be very grateful for some feedback what I am doing wrong.

```js
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

# Destination: user@host
set destination [lindex $argv 0]
# Destination password
set pass [lindex $argv 1]
# Expect timeout
set timeout 1000

spawn ssh $destination
expect {
  "hostname nor servname provided, or not known" {
    exp_close
  }
  "yes/no)?" {
    send "yes\n"
    exp_continue
  }
  "assword:" {
    send "$pass\n"
    exp_continue
  }
  "#" {
    log_file "./tmp/$destination.log"
    send "cat /etc/*release | grep PATCHLEVEL\n"
    expect {
      "PATCHLEVEL = 3" {
        send "zypper ar http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/up2date/SLES11-SP3-LTSS-Updates/sle-11-x86_64/ SLES11-SP3-LTSS-Updates && zypper mr -r SLES11-SP3-LTSS-Update;zyppe
r ref -s;zypper --non-interactive update\n"
        log_file
        send "exit\n"}
      "PATCHLEVEL =4 " {
        send "zypper --non-interactive update\n"
        log_file
        send "exit\n"}
        exp_close
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: After sending `zypper` commands, expect for the prompt `#`.

Comment: change `"PATCHLEVEL =4 "` to `"PATCHLEVEL = 4"` to align with your previous `"PATCHLEVEL = 3"`